# Firebase web app not connecting, getting console message: "...Error during WebSocket handshake: 'Connection' header value is not 'Upgrade'

Tags: firebase

This is a recent (as of 1 week ago) issue. Previously my app (and your site) was working on Chrome and Firefox. Under these circumstances:

Windows 7

Chrome 31.0.1650.63

FireFox 20.0.1

In a corporate firewall though I don't think it matters since...

IE9 works

I do not see this on a Mavericks browsers

I haven't changed my firebase cdn links in a long time and I notice the same issue on the firebase site.

Can you provide and insight?

Thanks.

Comment: This issue sounds more appropriate for support than StackOverflow. Can you reach out to support@firebase.com?

Comment: Absolutely and doing so. I was hoping the SO community might shed light on the issue as well.